# Using Azure Key Vault in Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do I call the password and email in Python for example: Assuming I'm using Selenium for some automation, how could I put the password in: "element = browser.find_element(By. XPATH, '//* [@id="gsr"]').send_keys('azure_keyvault_result')". The idea is not to pass the password in the Script and use the Azure Key vault, can someone help me please?

I tried to do it directly through Python itself in Visual Studio Code, it didn't work, I used the azure environment and still nothing.